# Saving countTimer() on interrupts (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, timer, oncreate

I am creating a game and I put a timer to onCreate method to display time to user and make an action when it reaches to 0. My way works correctly but since I wrote it to onCreate the time continues  to count down and if I rotate screen etc it resets the timer seconds. I know why this happens but I could not find a way to stop it when app is paused and make it continue from where it left of when application continues. Here is my code

```
 new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                question.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                question.setText("done!");
                Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CategoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(i2);
            }
        }.start();
```

Should I save milisUntilFinished to savedInstanceState and make the timer start depending on the savedInstanceState or is there an easier solution

Edit: So I updated my code to reflect the thing I ve asked. This way I can save the last state of timer when the phone is rotated, but timer still does not stop when I open the menu (pause the application.)

```
 if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("seconds");
            new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    seconds = (int) millisUntilFinished;
                    question.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    question.setText("done!");
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CategoryActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i2);
                }
            }.start();
        }else {
            new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    seconds = (int) millisUntilFinished;
                    question.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    question.setText("done!");
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CategoryActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i2);
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CounDwonTimer mCountTimer;
int seconds = 0;
```

then just cancel the `mCountTimer` in `onPause` and start in `onResme'

```
 protected void onResume(){
   super.onReusme();

   mCountTimer = new CountDownTimer(seconds*1000,1000){
       //......record the seconds
   }
}

protected void onPause(){
    if(mCountTimer != null)
       mCountTimer.cancel();
}
```

if your activity will **destory** when rotate the screen,you need `onSaveInstanceState`.otherwise you do not need this method

Comment: It worked when I placed countTimer from onCreate to onResume. I accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will help you,

```
private long startTime = 0L;
private boolean threadStop = false;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (isAdded()) {
            timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            //finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;
            time.setText(miliSecondToMinSec(timeInMillies));

            if (!threadStop)
                myHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (threadStop) {
        threadStop = false;
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - timeInMillies;
        myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    threadStop = true;
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I should use the handler inside onCreate right? and isAdded is unused. What does it check?

Comment: its in the fragment thats why I used isAdded to check whether the fragment is added to the activity or not. and yes, u start the countr in oncreate.

Comment: I upvote your answer, but accept the other one since it uses countTimer. This one also works